# See messages search matches in OS X High Sierra

Tags: macos, messages

I do a search in the messages application on High Sierra and it lists the conversations that have matches. But it only shows one match on the screen even it says there are multiple matches. How can I scroll to the next match in the same conversation?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer, it's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to go to the next result.